# Export Joined table an Feature layer based on a query

Tags: export, spatial-database, attribute-joins, excel, query-layer

I have a table and a layer joined fine, I am trying to export the end result into a file geodatabase, the export is fine if I specify specific name, other than that it exports the original layer data.
Here is the code I am using:

```
public void JoinLT(string DataPath,string Sheet, int lyrIndex, string JoinName, string TableFieldName,string FCFieldName, string FCName, string TableName)

    //Export the lakes from the GNE_Layer, to an already defined file geodatabase 
    {
        try
        {
            // Part 1: Define the Environoment
            IMxDocument mxDoc = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
            IMap map = mxDoc.FocusMap;
            ILayer layer = map.Layer[lyrIndex]; // GNE_Clip
            IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)layer;
            IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;

            IWorkspaceFactory WsF = new ExcelWorkspaceFactory();
            //Open the Excel sheet
            IFeatureWorkspace fWs = (IFeatureWorkspace)WsF.OpenFromFile(DataPath, 0);

            //Open table "tableName" 
            ITable table = fWs.OpenTable(Sheet); //Dynamic
            //ITable table = fWs.OpenTable("TroutLakes$");

            //Add StandaloneTable
            IStandaloneTableCollection ISTC = (IStandaloneTableCollection)map;
            IStandaloneTable SAT = new StandaloneTable();

            SAT.Table = table;
            ISTC.AddStandaloneTable(SAT);

            //Refresh Activeview
            mxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh();
            mxDoc.UpdateContents();

            // Part 3: Join the table to the feature class
            // Create a memory relationship class
            IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory memRelFact;
            IRelationshipClass relClass;
            memRelFact = new MemoryRelationshipClassFactory();

            relClass = memRelFact.Open(JoinName, featureClass,
               TableFieldName, (IObjectClass)table, FCFieldName, FCName, TableName,
               esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToMany);

            // Perform a join
             IDisplayRelationshipClass dispRC = (IDisplayRelationshipClass)featureLayer;
            dispRC.DisplayRelationshipClass(relClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftInnerJoin);


            IDisplayTable dispTable = (IDisplayTable)dispRC;
            IDatasetName srcName = (dispTable as IDataset).FullName as IDatasetName;
            IDatasetName destName = new FeatureClassNameClass() as IDatasetName;

            string LTOutput = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter Feature class name");
            destName.Name = LTOutput;

            IWorkspaceName destWsName = new WorkspaceNameClass();
            destWsName.PathName = "Data\\trial.gdb";
            destWsName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = "esriDataSourcesFile.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory";

            destName.WorkspaceName = destWsName;

            IFeatureClassName destFcName = destName as IFeatureClassName;
            destFcName.FeatureType = esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple;
            destFcName.ShapeFieldName = "Shape";
            destFcName.ShapeType = featureLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType;


            var queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
            queryFilter.SubFields = "*";
            queryFilter.WhereClause = "(GNE_Clip.Lake_Town = \"TroutLakes.Lake_Town\")";
            ISelectionSet selnSet = null;
            IGeometryDef geomDef = null;

            IExportOperation exOp = new ExportOperation();
            exOp.ExportFeatureClass((IDatasetName)srcName, queryFilter, selnSet, geomDef, destFcName, 0);


            mxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh();
            mxDoc.UpdateContents();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
    }
```